# How do I sort a collection of entries from multiple sections by date?

Tags: sections, sorting, queries

I want to create a featured story slider on my website and gather the *latest* entries from multiple channels to populate it.

Here is what is working:

```
# fetch the entries
{% set featuredBlog = craft.entries.section('blogs').limit(1).find() %}
{% set featuredArticle = craft.entries.section('articles').limit(1).find() %}
{% set featuredSpecialReport = craft.entries.section('specialReports').limit(1).find() %}
{% set featuredInfographic = craft.entries.section('infographics').limit(1).find() %}

# create a collection out of the above entries
{% set allEntries =
featuredBlog|merge(featuredArticle)|merge(featuredSpecialReport)|merge(featuredInfographic) %}

# loop over the collection and output them
{% for featuredEntry in allEntries %}
  {{ featuredEntry.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Now I want to sort the collection of entries by `postDate` so that the latest entry in the collection shows up first, no matter what section it is from. How do I do this?

I tried:

```
{% for featuredEntry in allEntries|group('postDate.day') %}
  {{ featuredEntry.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't work and crashes the template saying `Key "title" for array with keys "0, 1, 2" does not exist`

So how do I sort a collection of entries from multiple sections and show them by latest date descending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than fetching the entries at first, just grab their IDs using `ids()` instead of `find()`:

```
{% set featuredBlogId = craft.entries.section('blogs').limit(1).ids() %}
{% set featuredArticleId = craft.entries.section('articles').limit(1).ids() %}
{% set featuredSpecialReportId = craft.entries.section('specialReports').limit(1).ids() %}
{% set featuredInfographicId = craft.entries.section('infographics').limit(1).ids() %}
```

Then merge all of those arrays together:

```
{% set featuredIds = featuredBlogId
    |merge(featuredArticleId)
    |merge(featuredSpecialReportId)
    |merge(featuredInfographicId) %}
```

Once you’ve got that array of all the latest featured entries’ IDs, you can fetch their full entry models all at once:

```
{% set featuredEntries = craft.entries.id(featuredIds) %}

{% for entry in featuredEntries %}
    {{ entry.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this seems to be much more efficient but then how do I order the `featuredEntries ` collection by date descending? I want the latest item to show up first!

Comment: @AmitErandole Entry queries always fetch the entries in order of post date (desc) by default, but if you want to be explicit you can add `.order('postDate desc')` to each of the `craft.entries` calls.