# If merging two sections from different locales how do I then sort them by a shared criteria?

Tags: localization, sorting, merge

I've got a site with multiple locales and I want to merge together content from across these locales, eg News.

The two sections share the same fields so should theoretically be able to be sorted by a shared criteria.

Looking at the post at [How do I sort a collection of entries from multiple sections by date?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12522/how-do-i-sort-a-collection-of-entries-from-multiple-sections-by-date) I can merge these both into a single array but when I try to post the `ids` from these into a new query (to sort the results) only one set of results are returned.

Sample code:

```
{% set ids = craft.entries.section('news' ~ Section).relatedTo(active).ids() %}
{% set mergeIds = craft.entries.section('newsAlumni').status(null).locale('prior_alum').search('shareNewsAlumni:1').localeEnabled(false).ids() %}
{% set ids = ids|merge(mergeIds) %}

{% set news = craft.entries.id(ids).localeEnabled(false).status(null).order(['stickyNews desc','postDate desc']).ids() %}
```

If I dump the results of `ids` I get:

```
295484 | 3747 | 1787 | 1783 | 1781 | 1778 | 638 | 636 | 640 | 295486
```

295486 being the entry from `mergeIds` being returned.
However, if I dump the results of `news` I get:

```
295484 | 3747 | 1787 | 1783 | 1781 | 1778 | 638 | 636 | 640
```

Leaving out the result from `mergeIds`.
Any thoughts on why the entries from `mergeIds` are not being included in the resulting `news` object?

Ta

Cole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that last `{% set news = craft.entries.id(ids) %}` criteria model you're querying in one locale only
and there's no way to change that, Craft doesn't have a feature to set up a criteria model to query in multiple locales.

You'd have to merge the entry models themselves and use something like the [Super Sort plugin](https://topshelfcraft.com/lagniappe/supersort) to bring them in order.

```
{% set entriesA = craft.entries.section('news' ~ Section).relatedTo(active).ids() %}
{% set entriesB = craft.entries.section('newsAlumni').status(null).locale('prior_alum').search('shareNewsAlumni:1').localeEnabled(false).ids() %}
{% set entries = entriesA|merge(entriesB) %}

{% set entries = entries|supersort('sortAs', '{postDate}')|reverse %}
{% set entries = entries|supersort('sortAs', '{stickyNews}') %}
```

Comment: Thanks Carl - that was the approach taken:

    {% set pages = [] %}
    {% set pages = craft.entries.section('news' ~ Section).relatedTo(active).localeEnabled(false) %}
    {% set newsAlum = craft.entries.section('newsAlumni').relatedTo(active).status(null).locale('prior_alum').search('shareNewsAlumni:1').localeEnabled(false) %}
    {% set pages = pages|merge(newsAlum) %}
    {% set news = pages | supersort('rsortAs', "{ postDate|date('Ymd') }") %}